# First order condition of $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{t=t_0}^{\infty}{y_t}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{t=t_0}^{\infty}{y_t}^2$$ where $t=t_0,t_1,\dots$

What is the first order condition?

I'm a bit confused since if we differentiate this using $y_t$, the f.o.c is $$\sum_{t=t_0}^{\infty} y_t=0,$$
but using each $y_t$ then f.o.c is $y_{t_0}=0$, $y_{t_1}=0$, $\dots$

Both of them are true? I think $\sum_{t=t_0}^{\infty} y_t=0$ and  $y_{t_0}=0$, $y_{t_1}=0$, $\dots$ are different expressions.

Or is $\sum_{t=t_0}^{\infty} y_t=0$ just derived from $y_{t_0}=0$, $y_{t_1}=0$, $\dots$?

Comment: I don't really know how to tag here, but derivatives doesn't seem fitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be meaningless to differentiate this with respect to ***y***(t) since it is not a single variable.

So, f. o. c. for this expression is ***y***(t(i))=0 for all i=0,1,2...

About the last part,the summation is not derived from the f. o. c. but the other way around. This sum is a sum of infinite number of convex functions, so it is a convex function. Thus, the first order conditions give you the conditions which minimize this sum.